# How to get questions whose answer is not accepted | is:accepted filter in the question is not working

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, search

I am using `is:accepted` filter in the question but it still shows accepted answer

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Is it possible that those filter contradict each other? "isaccepted" sounds like something for answers, questions use "hasaccepted" and answers can't have "views", thus it is unclear (for the engine) what you're looking for.

Comment: I need questions whose answers are not accepted and questions view is greater than 3000, How would i achieve this

Comment: Or say Not accepted questions

Comment: As Tom mentions you want to use "hasaccepted" instead of "isaccepted".

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat thank you for pointing out that , i overread Tom's post. You could possibly answer the question i'll upvote it.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat quick question why is `inquestion:1234` filter used ?

Comment: @KrishnaAcharya the [search help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) should answer that: "_`inquestion:50691` restricts the search to the question with id 50691_"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the [advanced search help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)

> `hasaccepted:` yes/true/1 returns only **questions** that have accepted answers; no/false/0 returns only questions with no accepted answers.

So you have to try [`[tailwind-css] hasaccepted:0 views:3000`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btailwind-css%5D+hasaccepted%3Ano+views%3A3000) to get your expected result.

Comment: Yet, "isaccepted: yes/true/1 returns only answers that have been marked "accepted"; no/false/0 returns only answers that are not marked accepted."